# Java JPA - Relationship issue x Error Code: 1452

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, associations

[Here's description of my DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0JSp.png)

I want to persist object type 'TrenutnoIma' and I expect that it will also insert object type 'Komponenta' into my database ('Korisnik' is not being created, I've already got that objects made, my only problem is inserting these 2 objects into database and their relationship couldnt be made).

Here's code of my @Entity classes:

```
// *********** Korisnik.class (i'll put just main parts, dont want to put 
// unecessary setters and getters which arent important for this problem)

@Id
@Column(name = "idKor")
protected int idKor;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "korisnik")
private Collection<TrenutnoIma> listaTrenutnoIma = new ArrayList<>();


// *********** Komponenta.class (it's being made in same momment when 'TrenutnoIma' is)


@Id
private int idKom;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "komponenta")
private Collection<TrenutnoIma> listaTrenutnoIma = new ArrayList<>();

// *********** TrenutnoIma.class

@Id 
private int idTre;

@JoinColumn(name = "idKom", referencedColumnName = "idKom")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Komponenta komponenta;

@JoinColumn(name = "idKor", referencedColumnName = "idKor")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Korisnik korisnik;

// *********** Code I want to execute

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntityTransaction transaction = Menu.em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();     
    Komponenta K = new Komponenta();
    K.setNaziv("Component 3");
    K.setTip("Type 3");   
    TrenutnoIma tr = new TrenutnoIma(Menu.em.find(Kompanija.class, 2), K, 3, 3);     
    Menu.em.persist(tr);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

I try to execute that, and I got error in console:

[Here's print screen of my console, hope it's easier to see !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36pJ4.png)

My class TrenutnoIma has 2 foreign keys referencing, and set: on update cascade, on delete no action.
Thanks in advance.

- To add: Firstly i connect my main Entity and Relationship, and when i persist Entity, it says that in my Relationship table wants to insert or update primary key from Entity.
- Also when i manualy set up Entity primary key it works great, but I've put 'autoincrement' in Entity table so i'd avoid that manually setting primary key

Comment: where is "autoincrement"? You haven't put the necessary JPA annotation for that